# After Posting values From Meta fields form it is redirecting to the shopify app login page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I am new to the shopify app development area in Rails environment.
After Posting values From Meta fields form it is redirecting to the shopify app login page

I'm trying to create a replication of meta fields editor but with my own custom requirement.

my app url is http://shopify.app.dealodeal.techrevu.net

email ashok@inbox.com

skype: phpkidindia

App Code : https://www.dropbox.com/s/bglxtnts8oeo0us/app.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer from the source owner from github.